Understanding the difference/equivalence of an image stored on server vs. image data stored in a variable in PHP
I have some working PHP code that grabs a file from disk and sends it to an API as follows.
WORKING CODE - MAIN API
    $imagePath = "./myimagefile.png";
    $realpath = realpath($imagePath);
    $url = 'https://api.fastapi.com';
    $fields = array(
        'image' => '@'.$realpath
    );
    $ch = curl_init($url);
   //various cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

I now want to skip the step of saving to disk and send a file I've obtained from another API but am getting a no file sent error.
Here is how I get the file and display the file in the browser. It displays fine in browser so I am getting a valid image.
Helper API
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo ($response); //Displays the image fine

Here is my modified NON-WORKING code to capture the image from the helper API and then substitute it into the original API but it gives an error of no file sent.
NON-Working
    HELPER API
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    //header('Content-Type: image/png'); 
    //echo ($response);
    $imageData = $response; //Have tried this version and the encoded version below
    //$imageData = base64_encode($response);

    MAIN API
     $fields = array(
            'image' => $imageData
        );
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $response = curl_exec($ch;//no file sent error returned

It occurred to me there may be some difference between a file as stored on disk and one that displays in a browser after you set the mime type perhaps having to do with the encoding.
My question is can there be a difference between a file on disk and one stored in a variable?
Alternatively, what could be wrong with my file that is causing the APi not to recognize it?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

It depends on how this API https://api.fastapi.com works.

Get your code to work for the most basic case, just sending the unchanged file. Then you will know if is your special processing that is causing a problem.

I asked an LLM and got the answer. Because someone closed question, I cannot provide full answer but here is the beginning... "Yes, there can be a difference between a file on disk and one stored in a variable. When you store a file on disk, it's stored in its raw binary format. However, when you store a file in a variable, it's stored as a string, which can lead to encoding issues."
